# Google Web Fonts poorly rendered in Chrome. Solution?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I am using two Google Web Fonts at my website. They are Roboto Slab and Fauna One. They look good in latest Mozilla Firefox and IE10 but for some reason they look horrible in Google Chrome.

They are linked to my website as follows:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fauna+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

It took me a while to realize that Google Chrome has a problem with web fonts and that it renders them poorly. I am wondering if there is solution for this?

What if I download those two font types and embed them into the main directory of my website and then call them through CSS via @font-face property? Would Google Chrome in that case render those fonts nicely or I would still have the same problem and poorly rendered fonts???

Or there is some other solution for this issue?

Thank you all!

Comment: I tried the solution I proposed above. It shows the fonts I wanted to be shown but the rendering in Google Chrome is still the same. And it doesn't look good  How can I fix this? Anyone?

Comment: Out of interest, did you ever find a solution for this? I have exactly the same problem with Roboto and Chrome...

Comment: Hi Zac. I haven't found the solution yet. If you find it please contact me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I saw some bug report for Chrome where it was mentioned that this will be fixed - but I'm not 100% sure. I believe that it's not actually 100% the fault of Chrome...

My understanding is that the problem is to do with the *order in which font types are presented in the @font-face directive*. So, Chrome handles more than one type but not all types will render at equal quality. Apparently, Google actually doesn't serve the fonts in the right order from fonts.google.com - somehow...

In the end I found that, with `Roboto` at least (which I'm also using on a project), it is available for use on Font Squirrel (and open sourced under the Apache 2.0 license) - so you can download it here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto (download the Webfont Kit for full cross-browser font support) - you lose the CDN goodness of having it hosted on Google's servers if you use it from your own web server but, IMHO, I'd rather lose a few milliseconds than have to deal with such terribly rendered text...

I can't help you with `Fauna One`, unfortunately - it doesn't appear to be listed on Font Squirrel - perhaps you can find it on another font site? Or another similar font which is available on font squirrel?

Comment: you should be able to download any of the Google Web Fonts onto your desktop. Just add the fonts to "your collection" and there should be a "download collection" button somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure about that - I never took the time to check the licensing there. Good to know. Thx

Answer (score 0):

From a web browser perspective (Chrome being the browser in question), Chrome 35 in Windows has difficulty rendering some fonts, like Roboto, without some horrible artifacts that make the font difficult to read.

There is a feature called DirectWrite that will be included by default in future versions of Chrome that will fix this problem. You can enable it now in Chrome 35 by going to `chrome://flags` in your browser URL bar. You can `Enable DirectWrite` (experimental in Chrome 35), close your browser, open and try again.

Just to be clear, I discovered this problem on Chrome 35 for Windows. DirectWrite is a DirectX API for rendering fonts in Windows. Chrome by default uses Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) which seems to be the problem.

See [this article](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/chrome-font-rendering-windows/)